# How to create config file for helm. Like how we can mention cert and key in helm config file

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: configMap
data:
 [service]
  port: 3000
  Environment: "dev"
 [database]
  name:
  host:
  port:
[kube]
  server:
  cert:
  key:
metadata:
  name:
  namespace:
```

How we can add value when we create this file as helm config file

Comment: you add values inside `values.yaml` which store the values and use that values inside helm chart.

Answer (score 0):

As @Harsh Manvar mentioned in comments

> you add values inside values.yaml which store the values and use that values inside helm chart.

There is a link to [helm documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files/) about how to do it.

Specially part with

> Values files can contain more structured content, too. For example, we could create a favorite section in our values.yaml file, and then add several keys there:

**values.yaml**

```
favorite:
  drink: coffee
  food: pizza
```

**ConfigMap**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-configmap
data:
  myvalue: "Hello World"
  drink: {{ .Values.favorite.drink }}
  food: {{ .Values.favorite.food }}
```

Hope this answer your question.